# Factory method and parallel class hierarchy

Tags: oop, design-patterns

Dog is-a Animal.
Animal has-a House.
DogHouse is-a House.

A factory method ensures that Dog's House is-a DogHouse, but it's still typed as a House and I need it typed as a DogHouse.

There are lots of ways to solve this, but I'm wondering if there's a standard way. I'm writing in Objective C.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Generics.
For example, in Java:

```java
interface Animal<T extends House> {
    T getHouse();
}

class Dog implements Animal<DogHouse> {
    private final DogHouse dh = new DogHouse();
    @Override
    public DogHouse getHouse() {
        return dh;
    }
}
```

Comment: Nice! Objective C doesn't have generics, but it can somewhat be approximated using instancetype. https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/releasenotes/ObjectiveC/ModernizationObjC/AdoptingModernObjective-C/AdoptingModernObjective-C.html